# Catsitting a kitten

Tags: cats, behavior, introducing-pets

I will be catsitting a friends kitten for a couple of weeks starting next week, the kitten is a female, about 2 months old, not litter trained and probably not yet neutered last time I checked. I have a 5 yrs old male, his name is Marble and he barely ever interacted with other cats. I guess I should slowly introduce them to each other, but will the kitten learn how to use litter box from Marble and should I be worried about them fighting while I'm not at home. Marble never pees outside of his litter boxes, however he sometimes poops right outside of the boxes, I definitely want to avoid them urinating and marking territories, how can I prevent that and is it better if I separate litter box, food and water for the kitten?

Comment: You're adding a lot of simultaneous challenges here. Brining another cat into the house can be difficult and take weeks of gradual acclimation. Litterbox training can require feeding the cat, then keeping it in the litterbox until it goes; repeat as necessary. I would _not_ count on the kitten getting the idea from your cat, or interacting positively with your cat at all. I'd suggest treating this like a rescue: keep the kitten isolated with its own litterbox, and focus on litterbox introduction and spending some time in that room playing with the kit rather than trying to broker peace.

Comment: Definitely do not let them interact with each other unsupervised, an adult cat is easily capable of seriously hurting or even killing a two months old kitten. Cats are territorial to begin with, and with limited space in an indoor setting as well as little to no experience interacting with other cats, a very careful introduction is the prudent approach here. Best to keep both cats isolated when you're not around until you are 100% sure they actually like each other.

Comment: The introduction took a bit longer than I would expect, my cat didn't know how to react at first, took him a little over a week. He hissed a lot, he ate the kitten's food and cornered her, i just let them figure out, but I did have to separate them at night in the beginning, cause my cat showed some predatory behaviors specially the stalking, anyway it all worked out fine, they even slept together. Im considering adopting a kitten